# Azure Retention policy for new servers - will the first backup be retained long term

Tags: backup, azure, vault

We have an Azure tenancy with a a backup policy doing Daily(retained 30days), weekly (retained 10 weeks), and Annual (triggered on first SAT in JAN, retained for 7 years).
I have just migrated a bunch of servers from another tenancy into ours (company merger).
I want to know if the first backup of these servers (done last Friday, Feb 26th ) is going to be retained for 7 years, or if I have to wait till next January to know that I have a backup that will be retained for 7 years.

Answer (score 0):

No, the backup will be retained under which ever policy applies to it at that time, so daily or weekly. If you want a yearly one done you will need to run a one off backup with that policy or wait until January.